# Change class from not to print, to print by check box in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a lot of checkboxes and I only want to print the ones thats been checked. I've tried toggle, it works until I check it.

Here is my code:

CSS

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
.dontprint
  { display: none; }
</style>
```

HTML

```
<div class="dontprint">
  <div class="checkbox"> <label><input type="checkbox"id="coms">  \\Private\Computer Services </label> </div>
  <div class="coms">
    <select class="form-control">
        <option >READ</option>
        <option >EDIT</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$("#coms").click(function(){
    $(".dontprint").toggle();
});
```

Comment: how do you click anything when nothing is displayed, your css sets the display to none

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't toggle the visibility of the class, toggle the class itself.

```
$("#coms").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass("dontprint", !$(this).is(":checked"));
});
```

And to avoid having to repeat this code for each ID, you should give the checkboxes a class as well, instead of binding the click handler to a specific ID. Or if they're all inside a particular DIV, you can do:

```js
$("#container :checkbox").click(function() {
  $(this).closest(".hidable").toggleClass("dontprint", !this.checked);
});
```

```css
.dontprint {
  background-color: grey;
}
@media print {
  .dontprint {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="hidable dontprint">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="coms1">Checkbox 1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="coms">
      <select class="form-control">
        <option>READ</option>
        <option>EDIT</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hidable dontprint">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="coms2">Checkbox 2</label>
    </div>
    <div class="coms">
      <select class="form-control">
        <option>READ</option>
        <option>EDIT</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hidable dontprint">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="coms3">Checkbox 3</label>
    </div>
    <div class="coms">
      <select class="form-control">
        <option>READ</option>
        <option>EDIT</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't know how to make Stack Snippets open in a separate window so you can print it, but I made a jsfiddle, and it shows that the media query works.

http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/tyufjv6g/show/

Comment: And since he has _"a lot of checkboxes"_, he also needs to make sure to use a class instead of an ID, something like `$('.coms')`.

Comment: I get this error when I check the checkbox: Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: clicked
 

throw new Error( "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + msg );

Comment: Sorry, `:clicked` should have been `:checked`.

Comment: `.parent()` was wrong, I didn't realize how deeply nested the checkbox was. I've changed it to use a `hidable` class on the DIV that should be hidden during printing, and use `.closest()` to find it.

Comment: Great example but for some reason, it will not work for me. But this does the trick: `$(".dontprint").css("display", "block");` . Now only if i could get it to toggle when I uncheck :)

Comment: That will change the  CSS for non-printing, too. My solution works for me, see the jsfiddle.